# S3 operation failed; code: SignatureDoesNotMatch

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3

I'm running s3 as docker on my local machine:

```
docker run -p 9000:9000 minio/minio server /data
```

console output:

```
Endpoint: http://172.17.0.2:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000 

Browser Access:
   http://172.17.0.2:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000

... 
Detected default credentials 'minioadmin:minioadmin', please change the credentials immediately using 'MINIO_ROOT_USER' and 'MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD'
IAM initialization complete
```

I can view the s3 from my web browser (`http://127.0.0.1:9000/minio/`)

I want to check if bucket exists via python code:

```
    client = Minio(
        endpoint="172.17.0.2:9000",
        access_key="minioadmin",
        secret_key="inioadmin",
        secure=False
    )

    found = client.bucket_exists("aaabbb")
    if not found:
        print("Bucket 'aaabbb' not found")
    else:
        print("Bucket 'aaabbb' already exists")
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
minio.error.S3Error: S3 operation failed; code: SignatureDoesNotMatch, message: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method., resource: /aaabbb, request_id: 166D184DF48FFDD2, host_id: ad67daae-a8b5-4f5a-a977-c9a022c7c64d, bucket_name: aaabbb
```

What am I missing ?
How can I connect and check if bucket exsists ?

Answer (score 3):

secret_key is incorrect. change it to minioadmin